# How to decode XFDL to XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, base64, decode, xfdl

I have been scouring the internet trying to figure this one out. Any ideas would help. I'm trying to take an .xfdl file (base64gzip of XML) from my server and convert it to .xml with PHP for viewing and modification but, I can't see to figure out this process. I've seen people try to with Ruby but, I don't know any Ruby. If no one can help, I guess I'll be learning Ruby hahaha! Thanks in advanced. Also, I have looked through this website and couldn't find any php examples of this.

Comment: Is the XML gzipped first and then base64 encoded? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder, I'm not sure but, I'll try to decode both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the XML is gzipped first and then base64 encoded, you can use [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) and [`gzdecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php).

```
echo gzdecode(base64_decode(file_get_contents('file.xfdl')));
```

However if you're not running on a Windows box, you will [need to compile PHP with](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php) `--with-zlib` to include the zlib library and functions.

Once you have it in XML form, you might want to look at [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) to see how you can modify and read XML in PHP.

Comment: Don't laugh... I don't know how to complile PHP with `--with-zlib` or maybe I do and I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: @Cod-nerd Do you know how to use `phpinfo()`? If you're on shared hosting (or hosting where you didn't compile PHP), try saving this command in a file and viewing the file in your web browser. Do a quick search (Ctrl/Command + F) and see if you can find zlib anywhere on the page.

Comment: Ok. I see it on here. How do I enable it? I pulled my php.ini and it's not on there.

Comment: @Cod-nerd If you see it in phpinfo() then it probably is enabled. But just to make sure, try running `var_dump(function_exists('gzdecode'));` and see what that outputs.

Comment: @Cod-nerd Are you running your own setup with PHP or are you trying to run this in a shared hosting environment? If it's the latter you will need to contact your host to see if they can enable the zlib module in PHP.

Comment: Ok. yeah.. I'm currently using godaddy. But, when I can build a base, I plan on buying my own server. I'll contact them. Thanks for your help!